# How do I create a raster of distance to nearest feature using the terra/sf R packages?

Tags: r, geospatial, distance, terra

I have a simple feature object consisting of lines (roads), and I would like to create from this a raster with each cell representing the distance to the nearest line. In my case, a raster with the distance to the nearest road.

Here is a simple multi-line sf object:

```
library(sf)

#Code for multi-line string creation in sf
s1 <- rbind(c(0,3),c(0,4),c(1,5),c(2,5))
s2 <- rbind(c(0.2,3), c(0.2,4), c(1,4.8), c(2,4.8))
s3 <- rbind(c(0,4.4), c(0.6,5))

#sf multi-line string 
mls <- st_multilinestring(list(s1,s2,s3))
```

However, I have the additional criteria that I would like to stay within the `terra` or `sf` ecosystems as I am already using these and I am trying to limit my number of dependencies. I have found [a solution using `starsExtra`](https://michaeldorman.github.io/starsExtra/reference/dist_to_nearest.html), but I suspect that this problem is perfectly possible in `terra` or `sf`, and that it may be a little more efficient as my actual multi-line object is massive.

Here is the `starsExtra` solution:

```
library(sf)
library(stars)
library(starsExtra)

# Make grid
r <- make_grid(mls, res = 0.01)
d <- dist_to_nearest(r, mls, progress = FALSE)

# Plot
plot(d, breaks = "equal", axes = TRUE, reset = FALSE)
plot(st_geometry(mls), add = TRUE)
```

Is there any synonyms in `sf` or `terra` for `starsExtra::dist_to_nearest`? Or another way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Minor update, but the resolution at which I wish to make the actual raster in question is not possible using stars, as my PC does not have enough RAM for the operation and has been stalled at 0% for over an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could approach that with terra

```
s1 <- rbind(c(0,3),c(0,4),c(1,5),c(2,5))
s2 <- rbind(c(0.2,3), c(0.2,4), c(1,4.8), c(2,4.8))
s3 <- rbind(c(0,4.4), c(0.6,5))

library(terra)
v <- vect(list(s1,s2,s3), "lines", crs="local") |> aggregate()

r <- rast(v, res = 0.01)
r <- rasterize(v, r)
d <- distance(r)

plot(d)
lines(v, col="blue", lwd=2, xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

Computing distance on a lon/lat raster is much slower than on a planar raster. So if you have a large lon/lat raster you may consider projecting it to a planar CRS first.

Comment: Thank you for your help Robert!

As a note to others who might come looking here, Robert's solution works and does exactly what I asked. However, terra/my PC could not handle the operation on the layer I am working with (the entirety of North America at 1km res). If others encounter this issue, I found a work around that follows Roberts workflow but swaps out the `distance` function for `whitebox::wbt_euclidean_distance` which can perform the desired task much quicker. You will need to write the raster to your drive and then give `wbt_euclidean_distance` the file path as the `input`.

Comment: That is not a good solution unless your raster is planar (does not have a lon/lat CRS). I am asking because `terra::distance` is also much faster in that case; and you can use  `crs(r) <- "local"` before running `distance` to get the Euclidean distance. Also, what does "not handle" mean? Slow?

Comment: When I tried your approach to model the distance to roads for all of NA at 1km res, it took about 10 minutes for the progress bar for `distance` to appear, and was stuck at 0% for over two hours before I terminated. My CPU/RAM usage were low, but my PC did odd things like disconnect my bluetooth headphones and slow other processes. However, it did work on small subsets (~ +/- 10 degrees) but took about 10 minutes. 
The raster in question is in `lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)`. Following your suggestion I set `crs(r) <- "local"`, and it produced the desired output in seconds! What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please send me a message if you would like a reprex.